# Symbols versus variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I'm trying to migrate my database in a ruby on rails app, and I'm a bit confused about the proper syntax shown below:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change 
        create_table :categories do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.string :thumburl
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

(1) Why is a symbol `:Migration` being used at the class naming area? The way I'm reading it is that a class, `CreateCategories`, is being created, and it inherits all attributes of the `ActiveRecord` class. I was taught that the double colon signifies a class method call, yet the syntax coloring makes me think the `:Migration` component is actually a symbol. What's going on here?

(2) I get that `create_table` is a method, yet why use `:categories`, i.e. a symbol, instead of a class or instance variable, i.e. `@@categories` or `@categories`? I suppose you have to name the table that's being created, but why a symbol?

(3) Why are `:name` and `:thumburl` symbols and not variables?

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord::Migration` isn't a symbol, it's the name of the superclass being inherited from. `::` is the scope resolution operator, so `Migration` is a member of the `ActiveRecord` module.

As for why symbols are being used in various places, they're used in place of where you might otherwise use a String, such as giving the table a name. You could use 'categories' but as symbols are essentially just a pointer to an object, there's a certain amount of extra efficiency in terms of memory storage, as you don't have a new string being created everywhere that symbol is used.

To illustrate this idea, take the following script for example:

```
puts 'categories'.object_id
puts 'categories'.object_id

puts '---------------------'

puts :categories.object_id
puts :categories.object_id
```

Running of the script might produce something similar to this:

```
19608760
19608660
---------------------
839388
839388
```

The string versions have two different IDs, which means two separate String objects were created. The symbols version, however, prints the same ID, which means only a single object was created to represent the symbol, and the same object is used wherever the symbol is used.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your tokenization `:Migration` is wrong. It should be understood as `::Migration`. The `::` is a scope resolution operator. It means `Migration` as understood within the namespace of `ActiveRecord`. You are right that `::` is used as a class method call. Actually, `::` has two uses: the scope resolution operator, and a class method call; it is ambiguous. Here, it is the former.

(2, 3) `@@categories` or `@categories` or any other variable will be evaluated to a certain value it holds. It would not mean anything like "category". In order to tell something like "category", expressing it as `"category"` in a string, or `:category` as in a symbol is the way to go.